# Can I get a tableau view as an image in the size I want?

Tags: tableau-api

Let's say I have a Tableau view which I include via

```
http://tableau.MyViZ.com/MyWorkbookName/MyViewName
```

By `viz.getUrl() + ".png"` I can get an image of the view. However, that image does not have the size (resultion and probably aspect ratio) I want.

Can I call it in such a way that I can specify in which size I get it?

Answer (score 1):

Just add `?:size=1000,400`. The first number is the width, the second is the height.